# HAProxy performance issues

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to troubleshoot a sporadic performance issue in our production environment. We have an http frontend that points to a backend with 8 servers. In HAProxy http logs, there are hundreds of successful requests (~0.1% of requests) with unusual timings. These request timings are hovering around 1000ms, 3000ms, 7000ms, 15000ms, and 31000ms. The timing mainly comes from **Tc** column, which is the time it takes to establish connection to the backend (there are also a few requests that take 63000ms in **Tw** timing and have 1 retry). Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe those timings are a pattern that is used in TCP retransmission exponential backoff: 2^n - 1. Is there anything else that could explain these delays?

We have a pretty high **timeout connect** config of **10 minutes**, which I would like to change to **5 seconds**. My concern is what will happen to those strange requests that have a long Tc timing. Will the request return with an error, or will HAProxy use a different connection, perhaps to a different server (we have redispatch turned on)? We are only able to see this issue in our production environment, and so far we were unsuccessful at creating a load test in our testing environment that would replicate the issue. The production environment is configured with http health check with 3 retries 2 second apart. We actually have a few dozen failed health checks a day, but they recover every time on the first retry 2 seconds later, and the server is never marked down.

**UPDATE 5/24/2017:** We decreased the **timeout connect** to **5** seconds, which helped a lot. However, there are requests that hit the timeout and eventually succeeded due to retries (~5000ms when 1 retry, ~10000ms when 2 retries, etc.). Still puzzled why this is happening on a LAN. One interesting note is that we have multiple frontends: some run on linux while others are on Windows (IIS). The frontends with IIS servers are the only ones experiencing this issue. Has anyone ran into issue with HAProxy communicating with IIS?

Comment: Haproxy doesn't retry for you.  If it happens during a client connection they'll get an error.  But at least you can log that and try to debug it further.  5 seconds is a reasonable goal for your connection timeout, but maybe you'd feel better starting with 20 or 30 seconds and tightening it up as you catch and fix more of your outliers.

Comment: It turns out HAProxy does retry connections that timeout during connect. The number of retries can be [configured](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-retries).